# Getting NullPointerException while using Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Following code was an existing code in my project, using the same concept, I am updating the project,

```
public static List<Option> filterNetworkSettingsOptionBySetting(NetworkSettingsGroup group,
        String settingName) {
    LOGGER.info("************ Filtering Option based on SettingName ************");
    LOGGER.info("***** Setting Name "+settingName);
    List<Option> newOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
    if (group == null || group.getOptions() == null || group.getOptions().isEmpty()
            || StringUtils.isBlank(settingName))
        return newOptions;

    List<Option> oldOptions = group.getOptions();
    LOGGER.info("Before Filtering Options "+oldOptions);
    Stream<Option> stream = oldOptions.stream();
    LOGGER.info("Before Filtering Stream "+stream);

    newOptions.addAll(group.getOptions().stream()
            .filter(option -> option.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(settingName)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return newOptions;
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException at

```
newOptions.addAll(group.getOptions().stream()
            .filter(option -> option.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(settingName)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

this step..
I am not able to understanding that step, can anyone explain me the step clearly... what is happening in that step and how can I divide that step into multiple steps(because I want to check in method call null is coming).

Comment: seems like your getname is giving you null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you have asked to be explained is:

```
newOptions.addAll(group.getOptions().stream()
        .filter(option -> option.getName()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(settingName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`addAll` takes a collection so the statement inside returns a collection (a list, in fact).

`group.getOptions()` must be returning a collection. This should not be null.

`.stream()` turns the collection into a stream of items

`.filter(option -> option.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(settingName))` filters the stream of options to only have options whose name equals `settingName` (ignoring case).

`.collect(Collectors.toList())` turns the stream into a list to be added to `newOptions`.

In terms of checking for nulls, all the methods mentioned above are not able to return a null: they all return either a `Stream` or a `List`. However the `getName` method of options could be. So, realistically, it is either `getOptions` or `getName` that is returning a null value.

I would suggest changing to the following:

```
Collection<Option> options = group.getOptions();
assert(options != null);
assert(settingName != null);
newOptions.addAll(options.stream()
    .filter(o -> settingName.equalsIgnoringCase(o.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then the failing assertion will alert you to the null value. By switching the `equalsIgnoringCase` the code will filter out null names rather than throwing an exception.